# How can I change RadioButton content?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, radio-button

I have a question for you. I would like to set my WPF application to change my RadioButton only to their own content.I'm trying to create a math quiz where the user could choose one of three options.

I tried this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" };//is there any way to add those options here?
        public void ShuffleText()
        {
            var rand = new Random();
            var shuffledText = list.OrderBy(x => rand.Next(list.Count)).ToList();
            var radioButtons = new[] { firstOption, secondOption, thirdOption };

            for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.Length; i++)
            {
                radioButtons[i].Content = shuffledText[i];
            }
        }

        private void control_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            timer.Value += 1;
            shiftTimer.Start();
            if (vybOp == 0 || vybOp == 2 || vybOp == 4 || vybOp == 6)//this is enumeration selected operations
            {
                var answerRadioButtons = new RadioButton[] { firstOption, secondOption, thirdOption };
                var correctAnswerButtonFound = false;
                foreach (var answerButton in answerRadioButtons)
                {
                    if (answerButton.IsChecked==true)
                    {

                        if (answerButton.Content == result.Text)
                        {

                            correctAnswerButtonFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (correctAnswerButtonFound)
                {
                    shiftTimer.Stop();
                    call.Text = "Correct";
                    count++;
                    numberOfExamples.Text = count.ToString();
                    Random second = new Random();
                    Random first = new Random();

                    int maxFirst = 10;
                    int maxSecond = 10;


                    int secondN = second.Next(2, maxSecond);
                    int firstN = secondN * first.Next(1, maxFirst / secondN);
                    if (mark.Text == "+")
                    {
                        int total = (firstN + secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();

                    }
                     if (mark.Text == "-")
                    {
                        int total = (firstN - secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();

                    }
                     if (mark.Text == "*")
                    {
                        int total = (firstN * secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();

                    }
                     if (mark.Text == "/")
                    {
                        int residue = (firstN % secondN);
                        if (residue == 0)
                        {
                           int total = (firstN / secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();
                        }


                    }


                    timer.Value = 0;
                    shiftTimer.Start();
                }

                else
                {
                    shiftTimer.Stop();
                    call.Text = "Wrong";
                    poch++;//number of error
                    count++;
                    numberOfError.Text = poch.ToString();
                    numberOfExample.Text = count.ToString();
                    Random second = new Random();
                    Random first = new Random();

                   int maxFirst = 10;
                    int maxSecond = 10;


                    int secondN = second.Next(2, maxSecond);
                    int firstN = secondN * first.Next(1, maxFirst / secondN);
                   if (mark.Text == "+")
                    {
                        int total = (firstN + secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();

                    }
                    if (mark.Text == "-")
                    {
                        int total = (firstN - secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();

                    }
                     if (mark.Text == "*")
                    {
                        int total = (firstN * secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();

                    }
                    if (zmark.Text == "/")
                    {
                        int residue = (firstN % secondN);
                        if (residue == 0)
                        {
                           int total = (firstN / secondN);
                        firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                        secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                        result.Text = total.ToString();
                        }

                    }
                }


                timer.Value = 0;
                shiftTimer.Start();
                if (poch == 4)
                {
                    mt.Stop();
                    timer.Value = 0;
                    shiftTimer.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Game Over!");
                    end_Click(sender, e);








                }
            }
```

I prefer to send the whole code here so as not to miss anything (yes, it is badly written but perhaps functional). My problem is that I would like to Radiobutton(`firstOption, secondOption, thirdOption`)assign values ​​to their content so that one was correct. I would assign values ​​according to what the mark is as in the individual examples( for example

```
if (mark.Text == "+")
                   {
                       int total = (firstN + secondN);
                       firstT.Text = firstN.ToString();
                       secondT.Text = secondN.ToString();
                       result.Text = total.ToString();

                   }
```

But I have no idea how to assign it there.

If anyone has any questions, write me in the comments, I apologize for the combination of languages. I hope it's at least a little obvious what I mean.

Thank you all for any advice.[image]

Comment: Hey there! You should always use english variable names. Reading this is really hard for someone who doesn't speak your language. This way many more can engage on your question.

Comment: @Papriker ok i will rewrite on

Comment: @Paprikermaybe it's better

Comment: Don't you know how to set the `Content` property or what exactly is your question?

Comment: @mm8 Yes exactly, I would like to set the `Content`

Comment: @memberstack: To what?

Comment: @mm8 to set values ​​to be shuffled as answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update at 2021 05 13
```

It is very easy in WPF

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid  Columns="4">
        <UniformGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </UniformGrid.Resources>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding QuizTypes, Mode=OneTime}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQuizType, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

        <Button Content="Start" Command="{Binding StartCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Margin="20" Text="{Binding Quiz, Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding OptionView}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <!--Data template show you want by data-->
                    <!--OptionView item type-->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:OptionViewModel}">
                        <RadioButton GroupName="Answer" Content="{Binding Answer, Mode=OneTime}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>

        <Button Content="Answer" Command="{Binding AnswerCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

**important!**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.Commands;

namespace WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.ViewModels
{
    enum QuizTypeEnum
    {
        Add,
        Sub,
        Mul,
        Div,
    }

    class OptionViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
    {
        private int answer;

        public int Answer
        {
            get { return this.answer; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.answer, value); }
        }


        private bool isSelected;

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return this.isSelected; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.isSelected, value); }
        }
    }

    class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// command can handl some thing happend
        /// </summary>
        public RelayCommand StartCommand { get; }
        public RelayCommand AnswerCommand { get; }

        public QuizTypeEnum[] QuizTypes { get; } = new QuizTypeEnum[]
            {
                QuizTypeEnum.Add,
                QuizTypeEnum.Sub,
                QuizTypeEnum.Mul,
                QuizTypeEnum.Div,
            };

        private QuizTypeEnum selectedQuizType;

        public QuizTypeEnum SelectedQuizType
        {
            get { return this.selectedQuizType; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.selectedQuizType, value); }
        }


        private bool isStarted;

        public bool IsStarted
        {
            get { return this.isStarted; }
            set 
            {
                //if changed than return true 
                if (SetProperty(ref this.isStarted, value))
                {
                    //Change can execute state
                    StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                    AnswerCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        private ICollectionView optionView;
        /// <summary>
        /// CollectionView will be "options"
        /// </summary>
        public ICollectionView OptionView
        {
            get { return this.optionView; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.optionView, value); }
        }

        private string quiz;
        /// <summary>
        /// Quiz
        /// </summary>
        public string Quiz
        {
            get { return this.quiz; }
            set { SetProperty(ref this.quiz, value); }
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            StartCommand = new RelayCommand(OnStartCommandExecute, CanStartCommandExecute);
            AnswerCommand = new RelayCommand(OnAnswerCommandExecute, CanAnswerCommandExecute);
        }

        private bool CanAnswerCommandExecute()
        {
            return IsStarted;
        }

        private void OnAnswerCommandExecute()
        {
            IsStarted = false;

            /*
             To Do ....
             */
            OptionViewModel selected = OptionView.SourceCollection.OfType<OptionViewModel>().Where(x => x.IsSelected).First();

            int answer = selected.Answer;
        }

        private bool CanStartCommandExecute()
        {
            return !IsStarted;
        }

        private void OnStartCommandExecute()
        {
            bool start = true;
            Random first = new Random();
            Random second = new Random();
            int maxFirst = 10;
            int maxSecond = 10;
            int secondN = second.Next(2, maxSecond);
            int firstN = secondN * first.Next(1, maxFirst / secondN);
            List<int> optionList = new List<int>();

            optionList.Add(firstN);
            optionList.Add(secondN);

            switch (SelectedQuizType)
            {
                case QuizTypeEnum.Add:
                {
                    int total = ( firstN + secondN );
                    optionList.Add(total);

                    Quiz = $"{firstN} + {secondN} = ?";
                }
                break;
                case QuizTypeEnum.Sub:
                {
                    int total = ( firstN - secondN );
                    optionList.Add(total);
                    Quiz = $"{firstN} - {secondN} = ?";
                }
                break;
                case QuizTypeEnum.Mul:
                {
                    int total = ( firstN * secondN );
                    optionList.Add(total);
                    Quiz = $"{firstN} * {secondN} = ?";
                }
                break;
                case QuizTypeEnum.Div:
                {
                    int residue = ( firstN % secondN );
                    if (residue == 0)
                    {
                        int total = ( firstN / secondN );
                        optionList.Add(total);
                        Quiz = $"{firstN} / {secondN} = ?";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        start = false;
                    }
                }
                break;
                default:
                    start = false;
                    break;
            }

            if (start)
            {
                IsStarted = true;

                Random rand = new Random();

                OptionViewModel[] optionViewModels = new OptionViewModel[optionList.Count];
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var item in optionList.OrderBy(x => rand.Next(optionList.Count)))
                {
                    optionViewModels[index] = new OptionViewModel() { Answer = item };
                    index++;
                }
                //show
                OptionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(optionViewModels);
            }
            else
            {
                Quiz = string.Empty;
                OptionView = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.Commands
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private readonly Func<bool> canExecute;
        private readonly Action execute;
        private readonly EventArgs eventArgs = new EventArgs();
        public RelayCommand(Action execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            }
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged.Invoke(this, this.eventArgs);
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null ? true : this.canExecute();
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute();
        }
    }

    public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        private readonly Func<T, bool> canExecute;
        private readonly Action<T> execute;
        private readonly EventArgs eventArgs = new EventArgs();
        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
            }
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                CanExecuteChanged.Invoke(this, this.eventArgs);
            }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (this.canExecute == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (parameter is T t)
                {
                    return this.canExecute(t);
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.canExecute(default(T));
                }
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is T t)
            {
                this.execute(t);
            }
            else
            {
                this.execute(default(T));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NotifyPropertyChangedBase.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace WPFMvvmProjectTemplate1.ViewModels
{
    /// <summary>
    /// INotifyPropertyChanged let view can update when you property changed
    /// </summary>
    public class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// binding will watch this event
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (oldValue == null)
            {
                if (newValue == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    oldValue = newValue;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(oldValue, newValue))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                oldValue = newValue;
                RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
                return true;
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                {
                    PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Welcome to MVVM

Comment: This won't help me but thanks for the reply.

Comment: So you want to make a number test, and proivde 3 option (RadioButton) to selection?

Comment: I would like to assign content to three RadioButtons `firstOption, secondOption, thirdOption`. The point is that I am doing a math quiz and I would like the user to be able to choose the answer (one of the three correct) and I do not know how to assign values ​​for RadioButtons